# JQuery, how can i select the firstName and find the id out of the JSON String

Tags: jquery, ajax

Do anybody has an idear.
what is the outcom in alert, is it a usual string, an object or Json?
how can i select one of the Entities and find another out of that. For example, I want to select the firstname and find the id out of that. It schould be a Login script.

I am new in programming. What is this ? is it really JSON?

```
[
 {"id":1,"firstName":"Holger111","lastName":"Fink111"},
 {"id":2,"firstName":"Fink222","lastName":"Holger222"},
 {"id":27,"firstName":"ddsf","lastName":"fifi3005"}
] 



function searchMember(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/CustomerManagementWeb/api/v1/customers/all?",  
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
        mitglied = data;
        //var obj = JSON.parse(mitglied);
        //myJSON = JSON.stringify(mitglied);
        
        alert(data);
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Yes, thats JSON.</strike>(Read comments)

Check out the below snippet. Parse and create an object and then iterate to get id, name etc.

```js
var jsonString = '[{"id":1,"firstName":"Holger111","lastName":"Fink111"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Fink222","lastName":"Holger222"},{"id":27,"firstName":"ddsf","lastName":"fifi3005"}]';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $data = $('#data');
    $.each(myData, function() {
        $('<li> ID =  ' + this.id + '  | Name = ' + this.firstName + '</li>').appendTo($data);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="data"></ul>
```

Comment: JSON is a serialization format represented as a string. It can be deserialized into an object, but JavaScript objects and JSON are not the same thing. If the response type of the endpoint is specified as JSON, then jQuery will go ahead and deserialize it for you into an object, in which case it is not correct to call it JSON.

Comment: @JDB Agreed! Pardon my ignorance

Answer (score 1):

yes its a JSON array of objects. [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) guessed that it was JSON and parsed it for you :

> dataType (default: **Intelligent Guess** (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available
>   types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success
>   callback) are:...

You can use this to see a prettified version of the JSON : [LINK](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

If you are using Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I will open a developer inspection tool. You can see the network request and sthe results.

So as you see you have an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Holger111",
        "lastName": "Fink111"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Fink222",
        "lastName": "Holger222"
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "firstName": "ddsf",
        "lastName": "fifi3005"
    }
]
```

In your code :

```
var firstPerson = data[0];
var secondPerson = data[1];
...
```

To get the firstName for exmple you can use :

```
var firstFirstName = data[0].firstname;
```

for the id :

```
var firstId = data[0].id;
```

or

```
var firstId = firstPerson.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` argument is whatever was returned by the server. If the server returned JSON, then that JSON is usually deserialized into a JavaScript object.

According to [jQuery's ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.